# Is this hard-drive beyond recovery?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

A family member dropped a couple of their external hard drives as they were swapping to a new computer.
Needless to say both drives have been ruined, but with different symptoms; the first drive works but is unpartitioned (works but all data has been lost), but the second drive isn't even recognised in the BIOS and seems to have an issue with the motor of its spindle.

The second drive makes a 'clicking' sound every 1-2 seconds (irregularly) and I can also hear the hard drive's motor 'whining'.
[This is what it sounds like.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oxCtiOV-NEYnBYVVBVSTN3Mmc/view?usp=sharing)

Luckily the drive only contained recorded radio programs and TV shows, of which most were archived on another hard-drive anyway.

I have also noticed that a certain chip on the drive's PCB becomes too hot to touch after a couple of seconds of the drive being turned on- might this issue be resolved with a new drive PCB? The fact that the drive isn't even seen in the BIOS points to this?

Is it possible that this drive can be recovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a practical point of view, no, this disk can't be recovered.   It sounds like you have a problem with the drive heads, however even if it was just the PCB, the chances are that the cost of a new PCB is more then the cost of the drive.

Even if you do recover it, would you trust your data to it.  (Its akin to purchasing a very expensive car which you know to have structural damage in such a way that when it crashes their is no safety net - and then driving it at high speed).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few option to you short from using a professional drive recovery service.

- If you have an exact and identical hard drive, you could try swapping out the PCB. Sometimes as long as it's the same model line but a different capacity, it will still work.
- Seal the hard drive in a plastic bag with little to no air inside and then place it in the freezer for a day or so. Then while it is still cold attempt to recover the data from the drive.
- If it's a SATA Drive, try changing the SATA Mode operation on the motherboard IDE <-> ACHI <-> RAID <-> etc...
- Try a using a USB enclosure on a different machine.

Keep in mind that the more you mess with the drive and attempt to revive it yourself, the less likely a professional drive recovery service will be able to recover the data successfully. Also standard things like do at your own risk, you are responsible, blah blah blah.

Comment: 1) If only the PCB is damaged and you have an axact same drive then swapping it **might** work. Might. 
2) No. Do not put it in the freezer. (Nor in the oven). This worked in the past with drives who got slightly stuck (e.g. due to jelling oils).  It does not help against massive damaged or crashed heads. Instead you are likely making thing worse.
3) Changing SATA modes is as likely to work a sacrifice under a full moon near an ancient oak.  If the drive is not recognised at all in the BIOS then it is game over. Slußß. End. Finito.

Comment: 4) If the drive is not recognised when directly attached then putting them in an enclosure is as unlikely to work as option 3.

Comment: @Hennes Hey, I never guaranteed any results. I simply gave a list of items that could be tried.

Comment: True. But you include an option which is likely to make it worse / less likely to ever recover without a warning. Also, I read the post as disks coming from another desktop (not from external cases) and intending them to be moved to another desktop. Which makes point 4 also very unlikely to do any good.

Comment: @Hennes I did disclose the following: `Keep in mind that the more you mess with the drive and attempt to revive it yourself, the less likely a professional drive recovery service will be able to recover the data successfully.`  Also, sometimes miracles happen, and #4 could be one of them for that poor drive's soul.

Comment: You missed bullet point 5... "just get the data back from your backup"